# CMS page ordering solution for custom designed CMS

Tags: php

I wrote my own CMS solution and I have always had problems with changing the order of pages.  On my database I have a column named order which takes the automatic id of the page.  For example if pageid = 16 then order = 16.

```
function shift_page_up($pageid, $pageorder, $db, $database_db){

    mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
    $sql_previouspage = "SELECT order from pages WHERE `order` < $pageorder ORDER by `order` DESC LIMIT 1  ";
    $previouspage_result = mysql_query($sql_previouspage) or display_error(mysql_error());
    $previouspage_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($previouspage_result);

    $newpreviouspage_pageorder = $pageorder;

    $newpageorder = $previouspage_row['order'];

    $sql_update_currentpageorder = "UPDATE pages SET `order` = $newpageorder WHERE `pageid` = $pageid";

    $update_currentpageorder = mysql_query($sql_update_currentpageorder) or display_error(mysql_error());

    $sql_update_previouspageorder = "UPDATE pages SET `order` = $newpreviouspage_pageorder WHERE `pageid` = ".$previouspage_row['pageid']."";
    $update_previouspageorder = mysql_query($sql_update_previouspageorder) or display_error(mysql_error());
    }

function shift_page_down($pageid, $pageorder, $db, $database_db){
    mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
    $sql_nextpage = "SELECT * from pages WHERE `pageid` = $pageid AND `order` > $pageorder ORDER by `order` ASC LIMIT 1 ";
    $nextpage_result = mysql_query($sql_nextpage) or display_error(mysql_error());
    $nextpage_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($nextpage_result);

    $newnextpage_pageorder = $pageorder;

    $newpageorder = $nextpage_row['order'];

    $sql_update_currentpageorder = "UPDATE pages SET `order` = $newpageorder WHERE `pageid` = $subpageid";

    $update_currentpageorder = mysql_query($sql_update_currentpageorder) or display_error(mysql_error());

    $sql_update_nexpageorder = "UPDATE pages SET `order` = $newnextpage_pageorder WHERE `pageid` = ".$nextpage_row['pageid']."";
    $update_nexpageorder = mysql_query($sql_update_nexpageorder) or display_error(mysql_error());
}
```

So the main idea is to swap the order of the pages on the ORDER column duplicated from their page id's which are automatically generated.  I have already coded mechanisms to avoid swapping pages with the highest and lowest order using `SELECT MIN(order)` and `SELECT MAX(order)` respectively.

To shift the order up the anchor link `<a href="order_up.php?pageid=<?php echo $row_get_pages['pageid']; ?>&pageorder=<? echo $row_get_pages['order']; ?>&swapped=<?php echo str_replace( " ", "-", $row_get_pages['pagename']); ?>"> <img onclick="bounce_page('<?php echo $row_get_pages['pagename']; ?>');" src="images/ico/arrow-090.png" width="16" height="16" align="right" style="cursor:pointer;" /></a>` is clicked

To shift the order down the anchor link `<a href="order_down.php?pageid=<?php echo $row_get_pages['pageid']; ?>&amp;pageorder=<? echo $row_get_pages['order']; ?>&swapped=<?php echo str_replace( " ", "-", $row_get_pages['pagename']); ?>"><img onclick="bounce_page('<?php echo $row_get_pages['pagename']; ?>');" src="images/ico/arrow-270.png" width="16" height="16" style="cursor:pointer;" /> </a>` is clicked

**This beautifully works at times especially when the pages table is truncated and the page id's start at 0**.  *But an emptied table or a page deleted somewhere always bring issues.  When I click on any up or down link no values are swapped*

Comment: *"beautifully works"* ... ? Have you tried SQL injection? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: The fact that you're duplicating the IDs of the pages into the "Order" column tells me that you're over complicating things.  You should have an ordering method that allows you to sort on any of the columns (page title, ID, date...).  I would think that the order column should be all 0, unless specifically set in order.

Comment: @Axel The pages need to be specifically set in order.  The CMS user will click on either up or down button which invokes `order-up.php` or `order-down.php` so that they can manipulate the order of pages on the website's navigation bar to their liking.  Further more, as you suggsted, I would find it hard to track the changes the user has suggested. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I understand.  However presetting the order values based on the ID isn't intuitive and makes no sense.  You should be weighting items that have an order values to the top.  And why would `order-up.php` and `order-down.php` be two separate files?  Those are simple methods >.<

Comment: @Axel I agree on the two files and that they're simple methods.  This is dirty code that I never gave a thought to but it worked at 2 past 5 o'clock AM when you really need to get things working if you know what I mean. Anyway I like the idea of weighting but how would I go about it?